# unary potentials in graph cuts like optimization for computer vision

Tags: optimization, computer-vision, conditional-random-field

I am currently reading a paper which performs minimisation of energy function of the form:

$
E(z, \alpha) = U(z, \alpha) + \lambda V(z, \alpha)
$

Here $z$ is the image data defined in a uniform grid and $\alpha$ is some labelling we want to do per pixel in the image. Now, the paper went on to say that for the segmentation problem, given some real-world log-likehood ratio as:

$
    L(x) = \log p(z_{n}(x)|\alpha_{n}(x) = Fg) - \log p(z_{n}(x)|\alpha_{n}(x) = Bg)
$

My question is how can one create such a likelihood/appearance model from the image data. Say I have an image on a 2D grid and some initial foreground and background pixels marked by user. How would one go about computing this likelihood function? I am guessing there are many forms this function can take but does anyone know how this can be typically modeled.

If anyone is interested, the paper can be found here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/publication/geos-geodesic-image-segmentation/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how can one create such a likelihood/appearance model from the image
> data.

The usual way is to model the distribution of pixel intensities of each class ({FG,BG} in your case).  The *very* simplest is to assume constant variance Gaussian, in which you only need to estimate the mean of the pixel intensities for each class. You'd have two distributions: $p_{Fg}(z)$ and $p_{Bg}(z)$ (where I shortened $z = z_n(x)$ to match your notation).

Then

$\log p(z|α_n=Fg) = p_{Fg}(z)$

and similar for the background.

More complicated models fit different distributions, e.g. by storing histograms for intensities of each class.  Or they use more than just the intensity, say by computing a representation of the "texture" around every pixel and modeling a multivariate distribution $p(z_1,z_2,...z_N|α_n=Fg)$

Since you have pixels marked by a user, you can fit the distribution of your choosing over the variables of your choosing for each class, then you're all set!